# How to relate size parameter of .scatter() with radius?

Tags: python, scatter

I want to draw some circles using `ax3.scatter(x1, y1,  s=r1 , facecolors='none', edgecolors='r'), where:

- x1 and y1 are the coordinates of these circles
- r1 is the radius of these circles

I thought typing `s = r1` I would get the correct radius, but that's not the case.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To have a chance of helping, we need to see some of your code. Please consider adding that to your question, otherwise it isn't clear what is in your variable r1 that might be causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the value of 'r' (now 5) to your desired radius, it works.  This is adapted from the matplotlib.org website, "Scatter Plots With a Legend". Should be scatter plots with attitude!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(19680801)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for color in ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green']:
    r = 5  #radius
    n = 750 #number of circles
    x, y = np.random.rand(2, n)
    #scale = 200.0 * np.random.rand(n)
    scale = 3.14159 * r**2  #CHANGE r
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=color, s=scale, label=color,
               alpha=0.3, edgecolors='none')

ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```